# When is spacetime homogenous and isotropic?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

When is spacetime homogenous and [isotropic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy)?

For example, some metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ is homogeneous and isotropic. We now construct effective metric

$$n_{\mu \nu} ~\rightarrow~ g_{\mu \nu} + f(x^\mu)v_\mu v_\nu.$$

where $v_\mu$ is 4-vector, and $f$ is scalar. Is the effective metric $n_{\mu \nu}$ homogeneous and isotropic as well?

Comment: Hi tensor67. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site uses an unique TeX markup style called MathJax. This markup is very useful for understanding math equations and parameters. Please have a look [here for an intro](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) or our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation) for more info. For example, `\theta` results $\theta$, `\omega` inserts $\omega$, etc. It's quite interesting. You can revise your post if you can ;-)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24881/2451